# How To Deal With Hydrogen Peroxide After De-Yellowing?

Tags: cleaning, piece-usage, sustainability

I was able to remove the annoying yellowing effect from old white and lightgray bricks with the usage of hydrogen peroxide. With great results I have to say. Now I wonder what to do with the remaining fluid. Is there a danger to poison someone when it's used in my household? Is it ok to drain it down the sink? Any advice on how to deal with it is welcome.

Another thing, when do I have to change the fluid? Will the effect gradually decrease?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the handling of H2O2 is not tied to LEGO bricks in any specific way. This question seems better suited to Chemistry.SE

Comment: The dangers of H2O2 depend greatly on the concentration, which, in turn, will quickly change with time as it decomposes to water (heat and light speed up the process). So small amounts of diluted H2O2 can be poured down the drain, by the time it reaches the main sewer, there will be nothing left that would be more problematic than the average household cleaning products that get down there daily.

Comment: Interesting point. I would say it fits in both forums. And considering the special relationship of the members of this forum to the brick in particular I would say that there is a general interest here for the topic. So, no, I would not change.

Comment: You have a point, I'll let the other members have a say in how strictly are the rules to be interpreted. Meanwhile, to see if an amount of H2O2 is still potent, one just has to watch for bubbles of O2 being generated inside the liquid from the spontaneous decomposition. No new bubbles means no more potency, and thus time for a change.

Comment: ahh, seems i have to change. Thank you Zovits for your fast help

Comment: What to do with H2O2 if you don't want to wait for it to become harmless due to spontaneous decomposition, probably depends a lot on local laws, so this might also be considered too broad.

Comment: @ Fabian, I got great results using this method too.

Answer (score 2):

After doing a simple search, it seems that the general consensus is, it's okay to pour the *used* amount down the drain.

Most of us get it.  The stuff's been sitting in your house taking up space, and because of the unfamiliarity with this chemical, you and environmentally conscious thinkers such as yourself, would never want to further harm our shared environment.

Bottom line: No new bubbles means no more potency, the green light to pour away.